# How to cast into a type in GraphQL

Tags: graphql

For example, through [GitHub explorer](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/explorer) one can retrieve different types of time line items for a pull request (in this example `PULL_REQUEST_COMMIT` and `PULL_REQUEST_REVIEW`):

```
{
  repository(name: "react", owner: "facebook") {
    pullRequests(last: 10) {
      nodes {
        number
        timelineItems(last: 10, itemTypes: [PULL_REQUEST_COMMIT, PULL_REQUEST_REVIEW]) {
          nodes {
            __typename
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I now access different fields of the types `PullRequestEvent` or `PullRequestReviewEvent`? In other words, is there a cast or an if-then-else in GraphQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nodes` returns an array of `PullRequestTimelineItems` and a `PullRequestTimelineItems`is a GraphQL [union type](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#union-types). You can use the `...on`  notation to query for fields of a specific member in the union type:

```
{
  repository(name: "react", owner: "facebook") {
    pullRequests(last: 10) {
      nodes {
        number
        timelineItems(last: 10, itemTypes: [PULL_REQUEST_COMMIT, PULL_REQUEST_REVIEW]) {
          nodes {
            ...on PullRequestReview {
              body
            }
            ...on PullRequestCommit {
              url
            }
            
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```